# Printing the command line arguments in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am learning to pass command line arguments in python. I want to print the argument but I keep on getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fft_length'

My code is as follows:

```
import argparse
import configlib

parser = configlib.add_parser("MFCC config")

parser.add_argument("-fft","--fft_length", type=int, default=512, metavar="", help="FFT length")
args = configlib.parse()

print(args.fft_length)
```

The code for configlib is as follows:

```
from typing import Dict, Any
import logging
import pprint
import sys
import argparse

# Logging for config library
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Our global parser that we will collect arguments into
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, fromfile_prefix_chars="@")

# Global configuration dictionary that will contain parsed arguments
# It is also this variable that modules use to access parsed arguments
config: Dict[str, Any] = {}


def add_parser(title: str, description: str = ""):
    """Create a new context for arguments and return a handle."""
    return parser.add_argument_group(title, description)


def parse(save_fname: str = "") -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """Parse given arguments."""
    config.update(vars(parser.parse_args()))
    logging.info("Parsed %i arguments.", len(config))
    # Optionally save passed arguments
    if save_fname:
        with open(save_fname, "w") as fout:
            fout.write("\n".join(sys.argv[1:]))
        logging.info("Saving arguments to %s.", save_fname)
    return config


def print_config():
    """Print the current config to stdout."""
    pprint.pprint(config)
```

Can you please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `argparse` directly?  It seems like you're needlessly confusing yourself by wrapping it in a dictionary (for which the syntax for getting a value would be `args['fft_length']`, not `args.fft_length`, assuming that the dict has been built correctly, which I didn't check closely).  But regular old `argparse` will put it in exactly the form you're trying to use it in and would save you a whole bunch of unnecessary glue code.  If you need to save it to a file it seems like you could do that much more simply by just pickling the result of calling argparse.

Comment: @Samwise thanks a lot for your reply. args['fft_length'] worked for me. Actually I am trying to add something to my original code (one code with command line arguments called by another code with command line arguments) and hence used wrapping. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand your code, I'm going to rewrite it as a simple `argparse` use.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
new_group = parser.add_argument_group("MFCC config")
# assigning this to `parser` may be confusing
new_group.add_argument("-fft","--fft_length", type=int, default=512)
# args = configlib.parse()
# I think this is using configlib.parser, not the new_group
# 
args = parser.parse_args()
# then use this to update the `configlib.config dict
config.update(vars(args)
# then return the config dict as args
```

So if I've parsed this right

```
args = configlib.parse()   # this is the config dict
```

That would explain the error. `args` at this point is a `dict`, not a `argparse.Namespace`.

A straight forward parse would be:

```
args = configlib.parser.parse_args()   # returns a Namespace
print(args)        # diagnostic print
print(args.fft_length)
```

Changing the main script variables will help a lot:

```
newgroup = configlib.add_parser("MFCC config")
newgroup.add_argument("-fft","--fft_length", type=int, default=512, metavar="", help="FFT length")
configDict = configlib.parse()
print(configDict)    # diagnostic print
print(configDict[fft_length']
```

Comment: thank you for your response. It worked for me and I really appreciate your way of explaining.